# What is the build executable that make wants to use but can't find?

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, kernel-modules, make

So, I was trying to make the driver for my tplink, but when I entered "make", I got this:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.18.10-200.fc36.x86_64/build M=/home/dfmaaa1/rtl8821au  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.18.10-200.fc36.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:116: modules] Error 2
```

What does this mean? Why can't it find build?
The github repo is https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8821au.
I am using Fedora 36 Workstation. Kernel version: `5.18.10-200.fc36.x86_64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo dnf install kernel-devel` is what you're looking for. If it installs a new kernel part of the process, you'll have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Apparently there was a problem with the kernel headers. I installed the new kernel but booted into an old one. When I booted into the new one, the make command worked.